# Delete the document in the document library automatically based on the date sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, records-management, information-lifecycle-management

we have requirement to  Delete the document in the document library automatically based on the specific date in sharepoint

How this can be achieved using OOTB Features?

I know this will be possible through event receivers/timer jobs

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can use Information Management Policy to do that.

1. Go to your library->library settings
2. Information Management Policy settings->Document
3. Click "Enable Retention"->"Add a retention stage"
4. Then set the event like the below:
   [image]

A blog for your reference:
[How to set up retention and deletion policies for files and folders in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/)